# Imported GLTF is broken in Blender but works fine in a random GLTF viewer website

Tags: modeling, mesh, import, gltf

There's an incredibly annoying bug that I've found that's preventing me from moving forward on an important animation commission. I figured I'd ask about it on here as a last resort because nothing else I've tried is working.

Basically, I have a GLTF that I'm trying to import into Blender. It imports fine, but half the model is just completely missing. At first I thought it was a problem with the export file itself, but then I tried viewing it in a random GLTF viewer website (https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) and it worked just fine.

The model works fine in this online GLTF viewer:
[image: The model works fine in this online GLTF viewer]

Here's the errors that come up if I click the "2 Errors" button in the bottom left:
[image]

In Blender it's broken; Half the model is missing:
[image: In Blender it's broken; Half the model is missing]

Here's the error message that shows up when importing into Blender:
[image: Blender error message]

https://file.io/P8zWE8unh76Y (link to the GLTF I'm having issues with)

Comment: In the bottom-left corner of the viewer, you can see a tab showing there are two errors with the glTF. Click that tab to see the error report and post that. If the glTF has error, you will probably not be able to import it into Blender.

Comment: Added the image

Comment: The UNEQUAL_ACCESSOR_COUNT does look consistent with the Blender error. So the problem is with the glTF.

Comment: Is there any way to fix the gltf? I can't exactly re-export it very easily

Comment: Not an easy one I know of. You'd probably have to write a script tailored to this specific glTF.

Comment: Any other ways to fix it somehow?

Comment: I downloaded it and looked at it. Open the .gltf in a text editor, delete line 235657, and also delete the comma at the end of line 235656. Save. You should now be able to import it. This will remove the broken UVs on Mesh_445 (which is a wine bottle next to the ham), so be aware that mesh will be missing its UVs.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I think it worked